# std::shared_ptr _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) when changing pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, shared-ptr, sfml

When this function runs, I get the debug assertion error as described in the title on the line `sprite = spr;`. If I add `sprite.reset();` before that, it crashes on the line with `sprite.reset();`. The pointer is being stored elsewhere, in `static std::map<std::string,sf::Sprite> ResourceManager::sprites;`, so I would not expect the destructor to be called for the sf::Sprite either (although I have a suspicion it may be because they are being stored in a static object...?)

VisibleGameObject.h

```
#ifndef VISIBLEGAMEOBJECT_H
#define VISIBLEGAMEOBJECT_H

#include "Game.h"

//just for keeping track of the sprite and drawing

class VisibleGameObject{
public:
    VisibleGameObject(){}
    VisibleGameObject(const std::string& name);
    ~VisibleGameObject();

    std::string getTextureName();
    void setSprite(const std::string& textureName);
    void setSprite(const sf::Texture& texture);
    void setSprite(std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> sprite);

    void setPosition(float x,float y);
    void setPosition(const sf::Vector2f& position);

    void setRotationDegrees(float degrees);
    void setRotationRadians(float radians);
    float getRotationDegrees();
    float getRotationRadians();

    void setOrigin(float x,float y);
    void setOrigin(const sf::Vector2f& origin);

    sf::Vector2f getSize();
    sf::Vector2f getOrigin();
    sf::Vector2f getPosition();
    std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> getSprite();

    void draw(tgui::Window* wnd);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> sprite;
    std::string texture_name;
    bool _loaded;
};

#endif
```

Extract from VisibleGameObject.cpp

```
//'sprite' is initialised here
    void VisibleGameObject::setSprite(const std::string& textureName){  
        sprite = std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>(ResourceManager::createSpriteFromStoredTexture(textureName,name));
        texture_name = textureName;
        _loaded = true;
    }


//error function!
void VisibleGameObject::setSprite(std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> spr){
    sf::Vector2f p(0,0);
    float d = 0;
    if(_loaded){
        p = spr->getPosition();
        d = spr->getRotation();
    }
    sprite = spr;
    sprite->setPosition(p);
    sprite->setRotation(d);
    _loaded = true;
}
```

Extract from ResourceManager.cpp

```
sf::Sprite* ResourceManager::createSpriteFromStoredTexture(const std::string& texturename,const std::string& spritename){
    sf::Sprite spt;
    spt.setTexture(*getTextureByName(texturename));
    std::string name = spritename;
    if(spritename == standard_spt_name){
        name = spritename+std::to_string((long long)spritecount);
        spritecount++;
    }

    sprites[name] = spt;
    return &sprites[name];
}
```

The VisibleGameObject appears to function correctly when being used without changing the sprite with the setSprite function originally described as the problem.

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded program?  Is sprite a variable that could being accessed from another thread, and is being read from at the same time you're doing this write?

Comment: Can you show where sprite is defined and initialized?

Comment: Also, how are you creating the `shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>` you are passing around?  If the `sf::Sprite` is being kept in a map, why are you putting it into a shared_ptr?

Comment: Dave S: see edit. It is being kept in a static map in ResourceManager as a shared_ptr for the resource system but the actual object (the VisibleGameObject) needs to keep track of it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're failing because you're creating a `std::map<std::string,sf::Sprite>`, which actually owns the 'sf::Sprite' object.  You're then giving that a pointer to the object that's IN the map to a `std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>`, and using the default deleter.

This means when the last reference to the shared pointer goes out of scope, it will call `delete` on the object.  However that object is part of the map.  This causes undefined behavior (and in this case an assertion).

There are a few possible solutions:

1) Don't use shared_ptr in this case.  Since the ownership of the `sf::Sprite` is always with the map, then you can simply not bother with the shared_ptr and instead use a plain pointer.

2) Use a custom deleter that does nothing.  If you're interested in hiding the fact that the `sf::Sprite` is owned by the map (lets say in some cases you want to create it on the fly), then, you need to create a null-deletion function.  Here I'm using a lambda, but you could create your own function.  This causes the shared_ptr to do nothing when the last reference goes out of scope.  Since the memory isn't really owned by the shared_ptr, this is the behavior you want.

```
sprite = std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>(ResourceManager::createSpriteFromStoredTexture(textureName,name), [](const void*){} );
```

Edit:

Actually, I would go with a modification of the second option.  Rather than return a raw pointer, I would have the `createSpriteFromStoredTexture` method return the shared_ptr, and then use the noop deleter in there.  That way, the user of the function is not aware of how the sprite shared_ptr is created, it simply knows that it has a shared_ptr at this time.

3) Use a map of `shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>`.  The map will always own the sprites, but it makes the use of the shared_ptr a bit more natural.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Didn't notice that the shared_ptr in the VisibleGameObject was the last reference because of it being stored in ResourceManager. Would making the ResourceManager's map contain shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> instead of sf::Sprite be a good solution?

Comment: @Pig Head.  That would also work.  Let me add it to my answer, since it's also a reasonable solution